# Find usages of content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

I'm trying to delete a content type but it tells me to remove all references of it before doing so.

But I don't remember all the places where I have referenced it.

Is there a easy way to find them? Or must I look for it in every corner of the website?

Comment: Just note that you also have to delete any items using that content type from the Recycle Bin as well.

Comment: I did that already

Comment: Cool. That's just one of those things some of us learned the hard way.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of ways to find it.

1. Use the SharePoint Manager from Code plex

- Download the SharePoint Manager 2010 from Codeplex
- Open SPM and Navigate to the target Site Collection where your Content Type is located
- Go to Content Type >> Usages to find all content type usages
- Delete all the usages of the Content Type[image]
- Once done, You can delete your content type without any issues

2. Use the Powershell,

```
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
         
  # Get the site
  $site = Get-SPSite "<url of site>"
  # Name of the Content Type
  $ContentTypeName = "Travel Request"
           
  # Loop through all web
    
  Foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
  {
    
    # Get the Content Type
    
    $ContentType = $web.ContentTypes[$ContentTypeName]
           
    # Check if content type exists
    
    if($ContentType -ne $null)
    {
           
      # Get the Content Type Usage
    
      $CTypeUsages = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeUsage]::GetUsages($ContentType)
         
      if ($CTypeUsages.Count -gt 0)
      {
        foreach ($CTypeUsage in $CTypeUsages)
        {
          write-host $CTypeUsage.Url
        }
      }
    }
    $web.Dispose()
  }
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/the-content-type-is-in-use-error.html#ixzz42znYwDzs

Comment: Actually this image gave me an idea. The content type was linked in the Workflow Tasks list. Removing it allowed me to delete the content type. Thanks

Comment: The mentioned solution works only for sharepoint on premises, not online.
Sharepoint client CSOM doesn't have ContentTypeUsage property.